# PHP mysql_num_rows () expects parameter 1 to be resource

Tags: php, mysql, sql, function, error-handling

I'm having the problem being said on the title with this simple code.

```
//Only Validate if the date is unique
$checkdatequery = mysql_query("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM user_info WHERE date ='".mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_REQUEST['date']))."'", $db);
$rownumxx = mysql_num_rows($checkdatequery);
if($rownumxx == 0)
{
 echo'You are allowed to proceed.';
}
else
{
 echo'You are not allowed to proceed.';
}
```

I'm not sure what I did wrong with it. Thanks in advance to those who will help

Comment: what is TOP 1 ? use ORDER BY your autoincr key DESC/ASC LIMIT 1

Comment: sorry. i got used to odbc_exec codes so thanks for the one who corrected me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `TOP` keyword in MySQL , You should make use of `LIMIT`

Should be

```
$checkdatequery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE date ='".mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_REQUEST['date']))."' LIMIT 1", $db);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the query. Whenever you have such an error, probably instead of an MySQL Result you got a bool false due to some query error. As told in other answer. "TOP" may be your issue!

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
$checkdatequery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE date ='".mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_REQUEST['date']))."' ORDER BY YOUR_INCR/UNIQUE KEY DESC LIMIT 1", $db);
```

Comment: How do you know that there is a column named `id` ?

Comment: in database their should be the feild which is auto-increamented it can be id or anything else..but usually we use id..

Comment: A table need not have a compulsory `auto-incremental` field. It is _Optional_.

Comment: But to check the value in order thier should be an auto-incremental field according to above que.

Answer (score 0):

try this if want latest record:

```
     $checkdatequery = mysql_query("SELECT  * FROM user_info 
     WHERE date ='".mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_REQUEST['date']))."' 
     ORDER BY <key column name> DESC LIMIT 1", $db);
```

provide key column name whatever you have in your table 
 otherwise:

```
     $checkdatequery = mysql_query("SELECT  * FROM user_info 
     WHERE date ='".mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_REQUEST['date']))."' 
     LIMIT 1", $db);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
$date  = $_REQUEST['date'];
$checkdatequery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE date ='".mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($date))."' ORDER BY YOUR_INCR/UNIQUE KEY DESC LIMIT 1", $db);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using mssql as database

```
define('DSN', 'sqlsrv:server=localhost;database=dbname');
define('USER', 'username');
define('PASS', 'password');
$dbh = new PDO(DSN, USER, PASS);
$query='SELECT TOP 1 * FROM user_info WHERE date = :date';
$q = $dbh->prepare($this->query);
$data = array(":date"=>"your date");
$q->execute($data);
if(abs($q->rowCount()))
{
   $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
   echo'You are not allowed to proceed.';
}
else
{
   echo'You are allowed to proceed.';
}
```

if you are using mysql as database

```
define('DSN', 'mysql:server=localhost;database=dbname');
define('USER', 'username');
define('PASS', 'password');
$dbh = new PDO(DSN, USER, PASS);
$query='SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE date = :date LIMIT 1';
$q = $dbh->prepare($this->query);
$data = array(":date"=>"your date");
$q->execute($data);
if(abs($q->rowCount()))
{
   $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
   echo'You are not allowed to proceed.';
}
else
{
   echo'You are allowed to proceed.';
}
```